# Incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[100][1000]’ from type ‘int (*)[1000]

Tags: c

I have to make 2 programs. One that write a matrix on a shared memory and one that must read and order this matrix.

I created a shared structure that is the var that I will put on the shared memory. But I don't know how to read and store on another var.

My shared structure:

```c
#define QUANTIDADE 100
#define TAMANHO 1000

struct shared_use_st {
    int written_by_you;
    int num_processos_executando;
    int arrays[QUANTIDADE][TAMANHO];
};
```

How I create my matrix on the writer code:

```c
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < QUANTIDADE; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
            shared_stuff->arrays[j][i] = rand();
        }
    }
```

How I want to read from the memory:

```c
int my_arrays[QUANTIDADE][TAMANHO];

int main() {
    [...]
    my_arrays = shared_stuff->arrays; //Error
    [...]
}
```

Comment: You can't assign to an array, only copy to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign to an array directly.  You'll need to copy each element:

```
  int i, j;
  for (j = 0; j < QUANTIDADE; j++){
    for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
      my_arrays[j][i] = shared_stuff->arrays[j][i];
    }
  }
```

Or use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(my_arrays, shared_stuff->arrays, sizeof(my_arrays));
```